# How to declare a reference variable to persist between conditional blocks?

Tags: c++, variables, reference, conditional-statements

How should I declare a reference variable if I plan to use it throughout a number of conditional blocks? E.g.:

```
for (i = ...) {
    if (expr_1(i)) {
        // y[idx(i)] only exists when expr_1 is true
        // i.e. idx(i) is a valid index only when expr_1 is true 
        MyType &x = y[idx(i)];  
        ...
    }

    ... // Stuff not dependent on x

    if (expr_2(i)) {   // (expr_2 is such that expr_1 implies expr_2)
        foo(x);        // error, as x not scoped to persist to here
        ...
    }

    ... // More stuff not dependent on x

    if (expr_3(i)) {   // (expr_3 is such that expr_1 implies expr_3)
        bar(x);        // error, as x not scoped to persist to here
        ...
    }

    ... // etc
}
```

I cannot declare it outside the conditional block since reference variables must be initialized upon declaration, but the variable it references only exists within the conditional blocks.

Comment: you'll have to define it in the parent block, then check if it's been initialized/prepared in each block.

Comment: Well, `MyType byValVar; if (foo) { byValVar = y; } MyType &byRefVar = byValVar;`

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, but if `y` depends on `i` and so doesn't *exist* in the parent block for all loop iterations, what am I going to initialize `x` to? (Edited question to make dependency of `y` on `i` clearer.)

Comment: @Milo: Do you have to use references? If you used a pointer, just initialise it to NULL and then check for not NULL before you use `y`

Comment: There are no references in C. Did you mean C++?

Comment: Why is this tagged with C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would either of these methods work for you?

1. If you don't have a hard requirement to use references, try a pointer. Then you can declare it in the parent scope and initialise with NULL. Then later on check for not-NULL before using.
2. If MyType is an object you could have it derive from a base that defines IsInitialised() and then call this. If MyType is a scalar then if there is a value that is in-range of the type, but out-of-range for what the type represents then use such a value to indicate "not set" and do something like the following:

.

```
MyType notInitialised(NOT INITIALISED VALUE);
for (i = ...)
{
        MyType &x = expr_1(i) ? y[idx(i)] : notInitialised; 
        // code not needing x
        if (expr_2(i) && x != notInitialised) {
            ...
        }
```

Hope that helps?